# if statement in dropdown menu with condition in php

Tags: php, if-statement

Hi what i would like to do in my dropdown is to put a condition
if($formdata[0]['Phase']==1){
to show only the option values 0,1 and 2 in dropdown
but
if($formdata[0]['Phase']==3){
to show only the option values 0,3 and 4 in dropdown
here is my code

```
<?php } ?>
                                        
<div class="form-group col-md-12 col-xs-12">
<label><?php echo $t[$tmpvalues[0]['Lang']]['poles'];?></label>
<label>NUMBER OF POLES</label> 
<select class="form-control el-text-box" name="polesi" id="polesi" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                                                
<option value="0" <?php echo $formdata[0]['polesi'] == "0" ? "selected" : ""; ?> >None</option>        
<option value="1" <?php echo $formdata[0]['polesi'] == "1" ? "selected" : ""; ?> >1</option>
<option value="2" <?php echo $formdata[0]['polesi'] == "2" ? "selected" : ""; ?> >2</option>
<option value="3" <?php echo $formdata[0]['polesi'] == "3" ? "selected" : ""; ?> >3</option>
<option value="4" <?php echo $formdata[0]['polesi'] == "4" ? "selected" : ""; ?> >4</option>
</select>                    
</div>
```

Comment: OK, what have you tried so far? That should be quite straightforward to do. What about if the value is a different value than 1 or 3? Display all of them?

Comment: only these 2 values exist under 'Phase' conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways

1st using `if condition` as below

```
<?php if($formdata[0]['Phase']==1){  ?>    
<option value="1" <?php echo $formdata[0]['polesi'] == "1" ? "selected" : ""; ?> >1</option>
<option value="2" <?php echo $formdata[0]['polesi'] == "2" ? "selected" : ""; ?> >2</option>
<?php } ?>


<?php if ($formdata[0]['Phase']==3) { ?>

<option value="3" <?php echo $formdata[0]['polesi'] == "3" ? "selected" : ""; ?> >3</option>
<option value="4" <?php echo $formdata[0]['polesi'] == "4" ? "selected" : ""; ?> >4</option>
<?php } ?>
```

2nd way is using `CSS`

```
<option value="3" style="<?php echo $formdata[0]['Phase'] == "3" ? "display:block" : "display:none"; ?>"3</option>
```

same for other options according to your condition

Comment: second is not working as it doesnt show any values on dropdown menu and 1st has a problem,  i am not sure if i am doing something wrong

Comment: Can you share what the error is? Also, I have updated the second answer it was 'polesi' it should have been 'Phase' (this is incomplete you need to do for others option accordingly)

Comment: 1st option the if...... it makes the <option value WHITE

Comment: 1st now works with some modification thank you so much

Comment: ```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
<label for="d13"><?php echo $t[$tmpvalues[0]['Lang']]['d13'];?></label>
<select class="form-control el-text-box" name="d13" onchange="this.form.submit()">
<?php for ($j=0; $j<sizeof($ahk); $j++){ 
$selected="";if($ahk[$j]==$formdata[0]['d13']){$selected="selected";}
?>
<option value="<?php echo $ahk[$j];?>" <?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo $ahk[$j];?></option>
<?php 
} 
?>
</select>
</div>

Comment: now i have the same issue again with phase but now this code looks different which is impossible for me to realize how to apply the same condition, now for 1 i have values 1x10,1x20,1x30 etc and for 3 i have 3x10, 3x20,3x30 etc

Comment: If it helped you kindly mark the answer as useful and accept it.